# as3 array string to movieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

**UPDATED ANSWERED: Found a WORK AROUND.** I changed my array to an array of mc names rather than strings so it works now. Nevertheless, curious if this question could be answered.

---

I have a random array of string names. I sort them out randomly. But I need to add
an existing movieclip based the string name.

Here is what I have that doesn't work.

```
public function addToStage()
{
    Happy = sorted.sort( randomize );
    trace("First is: " +Happy[0]); /// Works! 
    addChild(Happy[0]); // Does not work
}
```

ERROR I GET
**TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "Apple" to flash.display.DisplayObject.
    at Main/addToStage()[C:etc..\Main.as:74]
    at Main/init()[C: etc...\Main.as:64]
    at Main()[C: etc... \Main.as:25]**

Comment: Are the strings class names, or instance names?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be working if I lose the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the strings in the array are names of MovieClip vars then it's as simple as this:

```
this.addChild(this[Happy[0]])
```

That effectively looks for a variable with the name equivalent to the string in the array, so this["hello"] will look for this.hello

If the strings aren't names of movieclip vars then you would need to "map" the movieclips to the strings using a dictionary or Object like so:

```
var dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary;
dictionary["hello"] = movieClipVariable;

this.addChild(dictionary["hello"]);
```

Let me know if this isn't what you meant and I'll have another look

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are dynamic, types are lost on children of the array, the are stored as Object.
to add the to the display list you must cast them to a DisplayObject or class that extends a DisplayObject:

```
addChild(Happy[0] as DisplayObject); // should work
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do type cast a from object to displayobject.

```
private var tempMC:MovieClip;

public function addToStage()
{
    Happy = sorted.sort( randomize );
    trace("First is: " +Happy[0]); /// Works! 
    tempMC = Happy[0] as MovieClip;
    addChild(tempMC); // it should work
}
```